# How to rotate Text in WPF by keeping the Auto-Sizing function

Tags: wpf, text, rotation

I want to have an text vertical. I just use a simple grid in WPF to auto-size the areas. But when using `RotateTransform`, all calculations are wrong. Any idea how to solve this?

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

[image: WPF rotate text]
In this image you see what I mean. If I now want to auto-size the middle part I cannot use "Width" or "Height" property because both will raise a wrong sizing result. Width =120px will increase the horicontal (original) width and will make the complete row 120pixel. Height=120px will make the text 120pixel height.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use a `LayoutTransform` instead of a `RenderTransform`. It gets applied during the layout pass, not during rendering.

Comment: In Blend, this is somewhat "below the fold" -- meaning that you see RenderTransform by default and have to expand the Transforms panel to see LayoutTransform.  I'd never noticed it there, but sure enough it's hiding in almost plain sight.

Comment: @Rachel Can UWP use the LayoutTransform?

Answer (score 40):

Like Rachel said use LayoutTransform

```
<TextBlock Text="Goodday" >
   <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
     <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
   </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>  
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock Height="14" 
    x:Name="TextBlock1" 
    Text="Vertical Bottom to Up" Margin="73,0,115,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" > 
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform> 
        <TransformGroup> 
            <ScaleTransform/> 
            <SkewTransform/> 
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/> 
            <TranslateTransform/> 
        </TransformGroup> 
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform> 
</TextBlock>
```