# How do I rotate a Label correctly using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an area of our page that I want to minimize to the side. When it is minimized, I want the area's "title" to appear rotated 90 degrees, but when I do it, it gets clipped to the unrotated height of the label, so it appears like this (the rotated text should read "Open Tasks Summary"):

[image]

Apparently, this is what is happening:

[image]

The section of the XAML that defines the label is below. I've tried several variations of Fill, FillAndExpand, StartAndExpand, etc. as well as setting the HeightRequest and WidthRequest properties. I've also done it without the StackLayout and with the Rotation being applied to the label and not the StackLayout and it always appears the same.

```
<StackLayout 
     HorizontalOptions="Fill"
     VerticalOptions="Fill"
     Rotation="90"
     IsVisible="{Binding DetailMinimized}" >
     <Label                                      
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding DetailTitle}"
            IsVisible="{Binding DetailMinimized}" />
</StackLayout>
```

So what is the proper way to structure the XAML so that the full text is visible after rotation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate Text in WPF by keeping the Auto-Sizing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458086/how-to-rotate-text-in-wpf-by-keeping-the-auto-sizing-function)

Comment: No, because Xamarin Forms XAML doesn't have a RenderTransform or LayoutTransform, but it is a similar issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Rotation` property of the `Label` instead of setting it on the parent `StackLayout`?

Comment: Yes, and I have removed the StackLayout entirely (I only added it because of a tip that said to rotate the container). Without the StackLayout and with the Rotation on the Label itself, it still has the same problem.

Comment: I have done a sample to test the Rotation="90" in the label, but it worked well.

Comment: I think it's because the container the label is in is narrow. I didn't have a problem with a 90 degree rotation on a label inside a large container, only when it was constrained by a narrow column (which is usually why you would want vertical text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to do this with a little negative margin hack.

[image: app screenshot]

Here's the code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="XfLabelRotationApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="auto, *" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid
            Grid.Column="0"
            ColumnDefinitions="*,auto"
            ColumnSpacing="0">

            <StackLayout
                Grid.Column="0"
                Padding="10"
                Spacing="10">
                <BoxView
                    BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30" />
                <BoxView
                    BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30" />
                <BoxView
                    BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30" />
                <BoxView
                    BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
                    HeightRequest="30"
                    WidthRequest="30" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Grid
                Grid.Column="1"
                BackgroundColor="#ddd"
                WidthRequest="30">
                <Label
                    Margin="-100,0"
                    Rotation="90"
                    Text="Open Detail By Dragging This"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>

        </Grid>

        <StackLayout
            Grid.Column="1"
            Padding="10"
            BackgroundColor="#eee">
            <Label Text="Main App Content" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Notice the `Margin="-100,0"` on the `Label`. If that's not there, the label would only assume the `Height` of its `Width`. That's how the `Rotation` property seems to work in Xamarin.Forms.

Hope this helps.